# /home/user: change directory failed error

Tags: users, home, accounts

I just installed Arch reading from the Beginners' Guide on the Arch Wiki. Once I rebooted Arch, I logged into root then I added my own personal account: `useradd fox` then `passwd fox` and set my password for the account. Once I logged in with fox I was prompted with the error `--fox: /home/fox: change directory failed: No such file or directory. Logging in with home = "/".`

Why I'm receiving this error and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell `useradd` to create your home directory:

```
useradd -m fox
```

You might also want to add options for group(s) `-g -G`, login-shell `-s` etc.

But don't worry - you can create your homedir now (as root using `sudo` or `su`):

```
# mkdir /home/fox
# chown fox:fox /home/fox
```

See [Arch Linux Documentation - User Management](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_groups#User_management)

Comment: Ah, thank you! Is it actually _vital_ to do groups?

Comment: @ErraticFox - No, I think the default for Arch is to create a group with the same name as the user, so your group is now most likely `fox`. For some applications it is necessary to add extra groups, like `audio`. Start simple and add if the need arises. You can check current group membership with either of the commands `groups` or `id`

Answer (score 10):

It's actually a SELinux issue. Not sure about Arch Linux's configuration but I encountered it when replacing my home directory with another (i.e. restoring it from a backup). You can check it yourselves with

```
ls -lZ /home
```

That prints out SELinux labels. Your home directory should have the *user_home_dir_t* label. The fix is straightforward:

```
restorecon -R /home
```

A longer discussion can be found in the [Fedora forums](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?281548-selinux-change-directory-failed-permission-denied).

Comment: In this specific instance, it has nothing to do with SELinux; the home directory didn’t exist at all.

Comment: In my case, exactly the fix I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly my case.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you!